# Java Need help implementing keyevent

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

Hi guys i have a school project and i need help on implementing java keylistener function. Right now i have made it with mouse listener but was asked to do the movement with the arrow keys.
here are my classes.

SpaceShipGame.java

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.Timer;






//import KeyboardExample.MyKeyListener;



import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;





public class SpaceShipGame extends JPanel 
{

private SpaceShip s = new SpaceShip();
   private ArrayList<Asteroid> aster;       //Array list to store the asteroids
   private int score = 0;                   //Initial score = 0
   private int lifeleft = 3;                //Player starts with 3 lives
   private int timeleft = 10;               //Player starts with 10 seconds of time
   private int x, y;
   private Timer countTimer;                //Count down timer for the time remaining
   private Timer asterTimer;                //Timer to move the asteroids
   private int delay = 1000;
   private int delay2 = 90;
   private int shootX, shootY;              //Get coordinates of asteroids when shot by laser
   private int collideX, collideY;          //Get coordinates of asteroids when collided with the space ship


   public SpaceShipGame()
   {
      SpaceshipListener monitor = new SpaceshipListener();
      aster = new ArrayList<Asteroid>();

      for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
           aster.add(new Asteroid(x,y));
       }
      addMouseMotionListener(monitor);
      addMouseListener(monitor);

      addKeyListener(monitor);


      countTimer = new Timer(delay, new CountdownTimer());
      asterTimer = new Timer(delay2, new AsteroidTimer());

      setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
      setBackground (Color.white);
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));

      countTimer.start();       //Starts the count down timer from 10 seconds
      asterTimer.start();       //Starts the timer to move the asteroids
   }

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame ("SpaceShip Game");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        KeyboardExample keyboardExample = new KeyboardExample();
        frame.add(keyboardExample);
      frame.getContentPane().add (new SpaceShipGame());

      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
      //draws the spaceship
      super.paintComponent(g);
      s.draw(g,800);

      //draws the asteroids
      for (Asteroid a : aster)
          a.draw(g);

      g.setColor(Color.red);
      //prints 'OH NO!!!' when the spaceship collides with an asteroid
      if(lifeleft>0 && timeleft>0 && s.getPosition().x==0 && s.getPosition().y==0){
       g.drawString("OH NO!!!", collideX, collideY);
      } else {
           g.drawString("", collideX, collideY);
      }

      //prints 'Score!!!' when the spaceship destroys an asteroid
      if(lifeleft>0 && timeleft>0 && s.getShooting()){
           g.drawString("Score!!!", shootX, shootY);
         } else {
               g.drawString("", shootX, shootY);
         }

      if (lifeleft == 0 ){
          g.drawString("Score: " + score, 20, 40);
          g.drawString("Life: " + lifeleft, 20, 60);
          g.drawString("Time Remain: " + timeleft, 20, 80);
          g.drawString("Game Over", 400, 400);
      } else if (timeleft > 0){
          g.drawString("Score: " + score, 20, 40);
          g.drawString("Life: " + lifeleft, 20, 60);
          g.drawString("Time Remain: "+ timeleft, 20, 80);
      }  else {
          g.drawString("Score: " + score, 20, 40);
          g.drawString("Life: " + lifeleft, 20, 60);
          g.drawString("Time Remain: " + timeleft, 20, 80);
          g.drawString("Game Over", 400, 400);
      }      
   }

   //Timer counting down from 10 seconds by every 1 second. Timer stops when time remaining = 0.
   private class CountdownTimer implements ActionListener{
       public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
           if (timeleft > 0){
            timeleft --;   
           } 

           if (timeleft==0) {
               countTimer.stop();
               asterTimer.stop();
               aster.clear();
           }
           repaint();
       }
   }

   private class AsteroidTimer implements ActionListener{
       public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
           for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
               aster.get(i).move();     //moves all 5 asteroids

               if(aster.get(i).getPosition().x < 0){
                   aster.remove(i);
                   aster.add(i, new Asteroid(x,y));     //removes and adds a new asteroid when 1 asteroid leaves the screen
               }
               if(aster.get(i).getPosition().x < s.getPosition().x+55 
                       && aster.get(i).getPosition().y + 30 > s.getPosition().y
                       && aster.get(i).getPosition().y < s.getPosition().y + 50){
                   collideX = aster.get(i).getPosition().x;
                   collideY = aster.get(i).getPosition().y;
                   aster.remove(i);             //removes asteroid when collides with spaceship
                   s.move(0,0);                 //moves spaceship back to (0,0) after it collides with an asteroid
                   lifeleft--;                  //life remaining - 1 after the collision
                   aster.add(i, new Asteroid(x,y));     //adds a new asteroid after the collision 
               }
               if(aster.get(i).getPosition().y < s.getPosition().y + 25 
                       && aster.get(i).getPosition().y + 30 > s.getPosition().y + 25
                       && s.getShooting()){
                   shootX = aster.get(i).getPosition().x;
                   shootY = aster.get(i).getPosition().y;

                   aster.remove(i);             //removes asteroid after it is shot by the laser
                   score = score + 1;           //updates the score when spaceship destroys an asteroid
                   aster.add(i, new Asteroid(x,y));     //adds a new asteroid after 1 asteroid is destroyed
               }
           }
           if (lifeleft == 0){
               asterTimer.stop();
               countTimer.stop();
               aster.clear();
           }
           repaint();
       }
   }

   private class SpaceshipListener implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
   {
     public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event)
      {
        /* s.move(event.getX(), event.getY());      //gets and updates the spaceship's position
         repaint();*/
      }

      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
      {
         s.setShooting(true);                   //draws the laser
         repaint();
      }

      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event)
      {
         s.setShooting(false);              
         shootX =0;
         shootY =0;
         repaint();
      }



      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event){}
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {}
      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
      public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

                if (keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT){
                    s.moveRight();
                    System.out.println("keyPressed="+KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
                    repaint();

                }
                if (keyCode == e.VK_UP){
                    System.out.println("keyPressed="+KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
                    s.setShooting(true);
                    repaint();
                }
                if (keyCode == e.VK_DOWN){
                    System.out.println("keyPressed="+KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
                    s.moveLeft();
                } 
                if (keyCode==e.VK_LEFT){
                    s.moveLeft();
                    y=2;
                    System.out.println("keyPressed="+KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
                     s.setShooting(true);                   //draws the laser

                }

                if (keyCode == e.VK_SPACE){

                }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        }
    }
   }
```

This is the SpaceShip.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class SpaceShip{

    private int xPos;
     int dx=0;
     int dy=0;
    private int yPos;
    private static int height = 50;     //height of the spaceship
    private static int width = 60;      //width of the spaceship
    private boolean shooting;
    private final String shotImg = "image/shot.png";

    public SpaceShip()
    {
        xPos = 0;               //initial x position
        yPos = 0;               //initial y position
        shooting = false;
    }

    public void move(int x, int y) {
        xPos = x;               //updated x position of the spaceship
        yPos = y;               //updated y position of the spaceship
    }

    public void moveRight() {

        if ( xPos + 1 < 800){
            xPos +=100;
        }
    }
    public void moveLeft() {
        if ( yPos -1 > 0){
            yPos-=1;
        }
    }
    public void setShooting(boolean value) {
        shooting = value;
    }

    public Boolean getShooting() {
        return Boolean.valueOf(shooting);
    }

    public Point getPosition() {
        return new Point(xPos, yPos);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g, int laserlength) {



        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillOval(xPos, yPos, width, height);      //spaceship body
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(xPos + 35 , yPos + 10, 20, 8);       //red window on the spaceship
        g.drawLine(xPos, yPos + height/2, xPos + width, yPos + height/2);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawLine(xPos, yPos + height/2 + 3, xPos + width, yPos + height/2 + 3);
        g.drawLine(xPos, yPos + height/2 - 3, xPos + width, yPos + height/2 - 3);
        g.setColor(Color.red);

        if (shooting)
            g.drawLine(xPos + width, yPos + height/2, laserlength, yPos + height/2);        //spaceship's laser beam
    }


}
```

And the Asteroid.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Random;

public class Asteroid {
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;
    private static int height = 30;     //height of the asteroid
    private static int width = 35;      //width of the asteroid

    public Asteroid(int x, int y)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        xPos = 800 + r.nextInt(50);     //initial x position of the asteroid
        yPos = 50 + r.nextInt(700);     //initial y position of the asteroid
    }

    public void move() {
        xPos = xPos - 15;               //move the asteroid to the left by 15
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.gray);
        g.fillOval(xPos, yPos, width, height);  //draws the asteroid as a gray oval 
    }

    public Point getPosition() {
        return new Point(xPos, yPos);       //returns the position of the asteroid
    }
}
```

am trying to move the platform object in an x-direction by using the left and right arrow keys. The if conditions for the keyPressed method work, after testing with some println statements but I am unable to move the platform object using keyListener. Is is something to do with the moveLeft , moveRight methods in the Platform class, because I tried d to changing the values of the dx, so I could maybe see some movement in the platform. I also tried to do the shooting with the keyup button but without success. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Maybe place print statements in the SpaceShip's move left and right methods to see if they are called correctly? Also your moveLeft changes the yPos instead of xPos.

Comment: Is the vertical space in the first file of steganographic significance?

Comment: So, where's `KeyboardExample`?

Comment: Oh `KeyListener`, how you make it seem so easy and then dash peoples dreams.  Ok. `KeyListener` has well known, focus related issues.  You could, spend a lot of time trying to manage the focus of the system, calling `setFocusable` on the component, `requestFocusInWindow` to try and obtain keyboard focus and it "might" work, sometimes.  Or, you could make use of the [Key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which solves this problem. Now, before someone points out that "this is an advance API", I'd like to point out, it's the right tool for the job